# Originate or originated

Tags: tense, verbs, aspect

What is the difference between.

> *The word originates from Thai*
>
> *The word originated from Thai*

Could someone please explain to me, thanks before.

Comment: Lol okay, just you know the word itself is already a past, like it came from somewhere, why should it has a present tense when it refers to the past.

Comment: what do you mean by "the word"? Did you mean the the word(subject) or the word(originate)?

Comment: Nah, I was fuzzy with this. The second one is passive construction.

Comment: Do the 'word' look like a past for you, I am looking for an answer actually.

Comment: I deleted the first commment. Originated in the second sentence is a passive verb

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, however http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/originate this site has shown that originated is used as an active construction for where was the thing from.

What makes me confused is, what is the use of present tense in this state.

Comment: Back to the deleted comment. If you use *The word originated...*. It means you are using simple past

Comment: Yes I do absolutely understand, it means that the word is from Thai, my question is, what makes it should be in the present tense, what's the difference between the past and the present of this verb.

Comment: The first sentence is more like you're stating a fact. But I dont think it's suitable in this context. I'd still prefer the passive construction "*..is originated"*

Comment: It is common to use the present tense when discussing the origins of words (but you don't have to).

Comment: @Mick That was confusing me so much.

Comment: @user178049 I wouldn't say "The word is originated".

Comment: @user178049 The passive "_is originated_" would never be used in this kind of phrase. When used in the passive voice, the verb would be  _transitive,_ with the meaning "to initiate, bring into existence". The usage here is _intransitive_ with the meaning "to take its origin (from)". There is no passive voice of the intransitive form, just as we don't say "He is looked". +1 to Stephie

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ohh, now I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is small, but tells a lot about the speaker's / writer's perspective.

Present tense (*originates*) is used to

- state a general fact
- emphasize that the statement is still true.

Whereas past tense (*originated*) is used to

- state that something happened in the past
- while the statement need not (but may) be true any more.

In your example, present tense would usually be the expression of choice, especially as it's a **general statement**:

> The word **originates** from Thai.

To make up a little counter-example (ignoring any linguistic facts, just for the sake of answering the question):

> The word **originated** from Thai, but was adapted to local language patterns in the nineteenth century, changing from "[*some sound*]" to "[*somewhat different sound*]".